# shader add transparency to black area

Tags: shaders, transparency, shader-nodes

I have made a shader in blender and would like any black area to be transparent. I am relatively new to blender so forgive me if this question is ignorant.

Here is a screenshot of my workflow:

[image]

How would I make the dark areas completely transparent but keep the white areas opaque?
I have a feeling it is to do with the `Transparent BSDF` and the settings on the right panel, but I have no idea how to go about working it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plug the math node to the Alpha input instead.
And set Blend Mode to *Alpha Blend* to enable transparency.

[image]